# Como sei se um adjetivo tá modificando dois substantivos? há, por ex., uma posição correta para estar?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, concordância-nominal

Sei que, se o sentido não abranger o substantivo, não há como o adjetivo modificar dois substantivos (ou mais) em coordenação (1):

- (1) Comprei pão, aveia, abacate e iogurte 'natural'.

No entanto, dificulta quando o adjetivo pode abrangê-lo, como contornar interpretações equívocas nestes casos? (cf.)

- (2) Comprei velhas gramáticas e manuais.

Me pergunto se seria o posicionamento, pra essa interpretação, tem de figurar o adjetivo após o último substantivo e fazendo uso da regra de concordância conveniente?

- (3) Comprei uma gramática e um manual velhos.
- (4) Comprei um manual, uma gramática e uma enciclopédia velhos/velha.

Comment: 2) Comprei velhas gramáticas e manuais. comparar /se contorna com: Comprei gramáticas velhas e manuais.

Comment: A gente termina ficando bem confusa.  Não tenho suficiente paciência para ver cada caso. :) Mas: Comprei uma gramática e um manual velhos. para mim deveria ser: Comprei uma gramática velha e um manual velho.

Answer (score 1):

Em geral, a posição do adjetivo não é determinante para indicar se ele está modificando um ou dois substantivos em coordenação. Em vez disso, é necessário levar em consideração o contexto e a semântica da frase para determinar qual é a interpretação mais adequada.

No exemplo (2) que você apresentou, "velhas" pode ser interpretado como um adjetivo que modifica tanto "gramáticas" quanto "manuais", ou pode ser interpretado como um adjetivo que modifica apenas "gramáticas". Para evitar ambiguidades, é possível reestruturar a frase de maneira a deixar claro qual é a relação de concordância entre os substantivos e o adjetivo.

Por exemplo, na frase (3) "Comprei uma gramática e um manual velhos", o adjetivo "velhos" concorda apenas com o substantivo "manual" (que é masculino e singular), deixando claro que apenas o manual é velho, enquanto a gramática pode ser nova. Da mesma forma, na frase (4) "Comprei um manual, uma gramática e uma enciclopédia velhos/velha", o adjetivo "velhos/velha" concorda com cada substantivo de acordo com seu gênero e número, indicando que todos eles são velhos.

Em resumo, para evitar ambiguidades em frases que possuem dois ou mais substantivos coordenados, é importante utilizar a concordância adequada entre o adjetivo e cada um dos substantivos, ou reestruturar a frase para deixar claro qual é a relação de concordância entre os termos.